# AJAX Request not working in Laravel 5.8.33

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.8

I am trying to make a dependent select field but When I select the first field Nothing happen to the other field. I think the ajax code is not working because I use an alert in the starting of the function call by ajax and alert didn't appear but still I am not sure what's the problem. What's wrong with my code can anyone help me in solving this problem.

Html code

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('search')}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="input-group col-sm-10 mt-5 offset-sm-1">
                 <select class="form-control" name="city">
                    <option value="none">---Choose City---</option>
                        <?php  foreach ($result['city_data'] as $city) {
                         ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $city->id;?>"> <?php echo $city->name;?> </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                 </select>

                  <select class="form-control" name="area">
                        <option>Choose City</option>
                  </select>

                  <div class="input-group-append">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn searchbutton" value="Search" name="search_button">
                  </div>
        </form>
```

Ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="city"]').on('change', function(e) {
            var cityID = $(this).val();
            if(cityID) {
                  $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }})
                  e.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                    url: '/myform/ajax/'+cityID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="area"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="area"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+value+'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
            else{
                $('select[name="area"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('myform/ajax/{id}','services4uController@myformAjax');
```

Controller.php

```
public function myformAjax($id)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Code reached to this stage');</script>";
            $area = DB::table("area")
                        ->where("id_city",$id)
                        ->lists("name","id");

            return json_encode($area);
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? The request is starting?

Comment: You are requesting JSON data, but prints the alert. This breaks the JSON parse on JavaScript side. Remove that alert code.

Comment: Make sure you are using your browser's developer tools (Javascript console and network inspector) to debug when you are developing with ajax.  This is absolutely crucial and will save you hours of guessing.

Comment: @fonini I am getting nothing nor any error neither any other thing... And I just add alert just to check weather the control reach to this function or not.. But After removing that alert the problem is still there.

Comment: @HammadAhmed Inspect the Developer Tools to see if the parameter is passed correctly. return json_encode($id); before the query to debug.